# (React testing) how to get container div's rendered class names

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm using jest, jasmine, and react test-utils for testing.

I'm trying to get the rendered class names on the most outer div of my component - so below, given I want the div to say `<div class='page-content banana'>` I would like to say something like:

```
expect(?).toEqual("page-content banana");
```

[As show in this tutorial](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/approaches-to-testing-react-components-an-overview/), I tried 
    expect(rootElement.classList[0]).toEqual("page-content banana")
But that throws an error, even with the same code in the post.

I would even be happy to run the getClassNames function in my test, but couldn't figure that out as well.

Logging my shallow output gets me:

```
{ type: 'div',
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  _owner: null,
  _context: {},
  _store:
   { props: { className: undefined, children: [Object] },
     originalProps: { className: undefined, children: [Object] } } }
```

// Page Container: (Reduced code for brevity )

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';

class PageContainer extends Component {

  getClassNames() {
    return classnames([
       'page-content',
       this.props.classNames
    ]);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.getClassNames()}>  // <- I want this
        {this.getHeadline()}
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PageContainer;
```

My Spec. I've tried using both shallow rendering, and rendering to the DOM:

```
jest.dontMock('../../components/shared/PageContainer.jsx');

import React from 'react/addons';
import PageContainer from '../../components/shared/PageContainer.jsx';

const TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

function renderedOutput(elt) {
  const shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
  shallowRenderer.render(elt);
  return shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
}

describe('<PageContainer />', () => {

  let shallowPageContainer, pageContainerRendered;

  beforeEach(() => {

    const component = (
      <PageContainer headline='I am headline' classNames='banana'>
        <p>The human torch was denied a bank loan.</p>
      </PageContainer>
    );

    shallowPageContainer = renderedOutput(component);
    pageContainerRendered = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(component);
  });

  it('should have the correct class names', () => {
    const renderedDOM = React.findDOMNode(pageContainerRendered);
    expect(?).toEqual('page-content banana');

  });


});
```

Comment: `this.props.className`?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I get this error when I try to access `renderedRoot.props.className` or `renderedRoot.className` from `let renderedRoot = this.renderer.getRenderOutput();` Any ideas? It's saying: `Do not access .props of a DOM node; instead, recreate the props as render did originally or read the DOM properties/attributes directly from this node (e.g., this.refs.box.className). `

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, but please note that I'm using plain Jasmine and testdom instead of Jest, so YMMV:

```
var rendered = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(component);
const renderedDOM = React.findDOMNode(rendered);
expect(rendered.getAttribute("class")).toEqual("page-content banana");
```